# How to make an activity under a tab scrollable programmatically?

Tags: android

i am developing an application where in i am displaying a tabbed layout on click of a button. now i want all my tabs to be scrollable. any help would be appreciated.

**Here is my code**

**AndroidTabLayoutActivity class** :

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyInfo.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MyInfoTab").setIndicator("MyInfo",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.myinfo))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Notes.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("NotesTab").setIndicator("Notes",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.notes))
            .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

   }
}
```

**MyInfo.class**

```
public class MyInfo extends Activity {
ScrollView scroll;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myinfo);
    }

}
```

**Notes.class**

```
public class Notes extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: `TabActivity` has been deprecated for **3.5 years**. Please use a modern tab solution: `ViewPager` with fragments for tabs, `FragmentTabHost`, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thank you for the suggestion. keep helping...

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks again for suggesting me to use modern tab solution. but for now, could you please help me in making the above old tabs scrollable.